# Cannot Save Data

Tags: php, laravel, forms, invoice

I was to Try to save any Invoice Card on Database but it not saved

What's Wrong With my code, I was Try to search to solve this but it not solved

Always Blank to database,

[The View Form & Post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVtVA.png)

The Controller

Use Boostrap 3 from AdminLte Template

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Kwitansi;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Haruncpi\LaravelIdGenerator\IdGenerator;

class KwitansiController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $kwitansi = Kwitansi::get();
        return view('user.formkwitansi', ['kwitansi' => $kwitansi]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $kwitansi = new Kwitansi;

        $id = IdGenerator::generate(['table' => 'kwitansis', 'length' => 10, 'prefix' =>'PM-INV-']);
        $kwitansi->received = $request->received;
        $kwitansi->registration = $request->registration;
        $kwitansi->course = $request->course;
        $kwitansi->trasnportation = $request->trasnportation;
        $kwitansi->payment = $request->payment;
        $kwitansi->kota = $request->kota;
        $kwitansi->register_at = $request->register_at;

      $request->validate([
        'sum_rp' => 'required',
        'sum_text' => 'required',
      ]);

      $sum_rp = $request->registration + $request->course + $request->transportation;

      function penyebut($nilai) {
        $nilai = abs($nilai);
        $huruf = array("", "satu", "dua", "tiga", "empat", "lima", "enam", "tujuh", "delapan", "sembilan", "sepuluh", "sebelas");
        $temp = "";
        if ($nilai < 12) {
            $temp = " ". $huruf[$nilai];
        } else if ($nilai <20) {
            $temp = penyebut($nilai - 10). " belas";
        } else if ($nilai < 100) {
            $temp = penyebut($nilai/10)." puluh". penyebut($nilai % 10);
        } else if ($nilai < 200) {
            $temp = " seratus" . penyebut($nilai - 100);
        } else if ($nilai < 1000) {
            $temp = penyebut($nilai/100) . " ratus" . penyebut($nilai % 100);
        } else if ($nilai < 2000) {
            $temp = " seribu" . penyebut($nilai - 1000);
        } else if ($nilai < 1000000) {
            $temp = penyebut($nilai/1000) . " ribu" . penyebut($nilai % 1000);
        } else if ($nilai < 1000000000) {
            $temp = penyebut($nilai/1000000) . " juta" . penyebut($nilai % 1000000);
        } else if ($nilai < 1000000000000) {
            $temp = penyebut($nilai/1000000000) . " milyar" . penyebut(fmod($nilai,1000000000));
        } else if ($nilai < 1000000000000000) {
            $temp = penyebut($nilai/1000000000000) . " trilyun" . penyebut(fmod($nilai,1000000000000));
        }     
        return $temp;
    }
    function terbilang($nilai) {
        if($nilai<0) {
            $hasil = "minus ". trim(penyebut($nilai));
        } else {
            $hasil = trim(penyebut($nilai));
        }           
        return $hasil;
    }
    $sum_text = $request->sum_rp;

    $kwitansi->sum_rp = $sum_rp;
    $kwitansi->sum_text = terbilang($sum_text);

    $kwitansi->save();

    return redirect('kwitansi')->withSuccess('Added Succesfully');
    }
}
```

The Blade View

Use Form and View in One Page

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('title', 'Kwitansi')

@section('css')

<!-- DataTables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('adminlte/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css') }}">
@section('js')
<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="{{ asset('adminlte/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('adminlte/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js') }}"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#example1").DataTable();
    $('#example2').DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "searching": false,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": false,
    });
  });
</script>

@endsection

@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h3 class="card-title">DataTable User</h3>
              @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
              <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <h5><i class="icon fas fa-check"></i> Alert!</h5>
                  <p>{{ $message }}</p>
              </div>
              @endif
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-header -->
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="{{ route('kwitansi.store') }}" method="POST" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="name" class="control-label col-md-2">Terima Dari</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="received" class="form-control" placeholder="Received Form" />
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="registration" class="control-label col-md-2">Biaya Registrasi</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="registration" class="form-control" placeholder="Registration Fee" />
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="course" class="control-label col-md-2">Biaya Kursus</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="course" class="form-control" placeholder="Course Fee" />
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="trasnportation" class="control-label col-md-2">Biaya Transportasi</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="trasnportation" class="form-control" placeholder="Transportation Fee" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="payment" class="control-label col-md-2">Pembayaran Untuk</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="payment" class="form-control" placeholder="Payment Of" />
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="register_at" class="control-label col-md-2">Tanggal Registrasi</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="kota"class="form-control" value="Bandung" disabled hidden>
                            <input type="date" name="register_at"class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnsubmit">Tambah Data</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" id="btncancel">Cancel</button>
                </form>
              <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>No.</th>
                  <th>received</th>
                  <th>registration Fee</th>
                  <th>Course Fee</th>
                  <th>Transportation Fee</th>
                  <th>Grand Total</th>
                  <th>Payment of</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($kwitansi as $k)
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ $k->id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $k->received }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $k->registration }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $k->course }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $k->transportation }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $k->sum_rp }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $k->payment }}</td>
                  <td>
                    {{-- <a href="{{ route('user.edit', $u->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                    <a href="{{ route('user.show', $u->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info"><i class="fas fa-file"></i></a>
                    <form action="{{ route('user.destroy', $u->id)}}" method="post">
                          @csrf
                          @method('DELETE')
                          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                        </form> --}}
                  </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>received</th>
                    <th>registration Fee</th>
                    <th>Course Fee</th>
                    <th>Transportation Fee</th>
                    <th>Grand Total</th>
                    <th>Payment of</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
              </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.card -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->

@endsection
```

I used form and view in one page are this is the problem

This is my model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Kwitansi extends Model
{
    // $id = IdGenerator::generate(['table' => 'kwitansis', 'length' => 10, 'prefix' =>'PM-INV-']);
    protected $table = 'kwitansis';
    protected $fillable = [
        'received',
        'registration',
        'course',
        'trasnportation',
        'sum_rp',
        'payment',
        'register_at',
    ];
    protected $primarykey = 'id';

    public $increment = false;

    protected $keyType = 'string';
}
```

Comment: Please show your Kwitansi model.

Comment: First, you have a lot of unnecessary codes like you can do this: $kwitansiData = $request->only(['received','registeration',...]);
Kwitansi::create($kwitansiData); instead of filling data one by one
Secound, you can dump kwitansi data before save() method to see that there is any data in kwitansi object you created or not

Comment: Ok I Will Try @HassanShojaei

Comment: @QumberRizvi THis My Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Thanks Guys For Helping, I Have Solved The Problem.

I Only Delete Some function on Controller adn Worked for Me

```
$request->validate([
        'sum_rp' => 'required',
        'sum_text' => 'required',
      ]);

      $sum_rp = $request->registration + $request->course + $request->transportation;

      function penyebut($nilai) {
        $nilai = abs($nilai);
        $huruf = array("", "satu", "dua", "tiga", "empat", "lima", "enam", "tujuh", "delapan", "sembilan", "sepuluh", "sebelas");
        $temp = "";
        if ($nilai < 12) {
            $temp = " ". $huruf[$nilai];
        } else if ($nilai <20) {
            $temp = penyebut($nilai - 10). " belas";
        } else if ($nilai < 100) {
            $temp = penyebut($nilai/10)." puluh". penyebut($nilai % 10);
        } else if ($nilai < 200) {
            $temp = " seratus" . penyebut($nilai - 100);
        } else if ($nilai < 1000) {
            $temp = penyebut($nilai/100) . " ratus" . penyebut($nilai % 100);
        } else if ($nilai < 2000) {
            $temp = " seribu" . penyebut($nilai - 1000);
        } else if ($nilai < 1000000) {
            $temp = penyebut($nilai/1000) . " ribu" . penyebut($nilai % 1000);
        } else if ($nilai < 1000000000) {
            $temp = penyebut($nilai/1000000) . " juta" . penyebut($nilai % 1000000);
        } else if ($nilai < 1000000000000) {
            $temp = penyebut($nilai/1000000000) . " milyar" . penyebut(fmod($nilai,1000000000));
        } else if ($nilai < 1000000000000000) {
            $temp = penyebut($nilai/1000000000000) . " trilyun" . penyebut(fmod($nilai,1000000000000));
        }     
        return $temp;
    }
    function terbilang($nilai) {
        if($nilai<0) {
            $hasil = "minus ". trim(penyebut($nilai));
        } else {
            $hasil = trim(penyebut($nilai));
        }           
        return $hasil;
    }
    $sum_text = $request->sum_rp;

    $kwitansi->sum_rp = $sum_rp;
    $kwitansi->sum_text = terbilang($sum_text);
```

Only Delete This function and add it to Helper Class

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines from your model:

```
protected $primarykey = 'id';

public $increment = false;

protected $keyType = 'string';
```

Comment: If this line removed the ID is 0 and can't add any data again

Comment: You can modify your auto-increment value from the database itself. In case of MySQL: `ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 5;`

Comment: If this doesn't fork for you, I'd like to see your table structure for table `kwitansis`.